# Trying to install cifs-utils - the attempt created dependency hell

Tags: apt, mount, dpkg, dependencies, cifs

Trying to mount a smb share in Linux (12-10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic) - I tried to install mounting utils

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

response / error:

```
...
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-10_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-10) over (2.13+git20120306-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-10_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/update-locale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu20
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-dev-bin_2.19-10_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.19-10) over (2.15-0ubuntu20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.19-10_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:i386 (2.19-10) over (2.15-0ubuntu20) ...
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of locales, which would be broken by installation of libc6:i386 ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure locales (broken by libc6:i386)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.19-10_i386.deb ...
De-configuring locales (2.13+git20120306-3) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.19-10) over (2.15-0ubuntu20) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-10_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

me:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

response / error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Recommends: libc6-i686
         Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-10 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

me:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

response / error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-10_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-10) over (2.13+git20120306-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-10_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/update-locale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu20
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-10_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Idk how to get around these errors... How can I do a simple operation like mount ?

**Update:**

```
  sudo apt-get update
```

response

```
....
Fetched 233 kB in 2min 14s (1,730 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

me:
    sudo apt-get upgrade

Respone - error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Recommends: libc6-i686
         Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-10 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**New update** - looked at install history - and the took a second look at the install above...

```
Commandline: apt-get install cifs-utils
Install: python-crypto:i386 (2.6.1-5+b1, automatic), python-dnspython:i386 (1.11.1-1, automatic), libaio1:i386 (0.3.109-4, automatic), samba-vfs-modules:i386 (4.1.11+dfsg-1, automatic), libtasn1-6:i386 (4.1-2, automatic), python-ntdb:i386 (1.0-5, automatic), tdb-tools:i386 (1.3.0-1.1, automatic), python-ldb:i386 (1.1.17-1, automatic), python-talloc:i386 (2.1.1-2, automatic), libc6-i686:i386 (2.19-10, automatic), libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.8-6, automatic), python-tdb:i386 (1.3.0-1.1, automatic), attr:i386 (2.4.47-1, automatic), libkdc2-heimdal:i386 (1.6~rc2+dfsg-8, automatic), libntdb1:i386 (1.0-5, automatic), libtevent0:i386 (0.9.21-1, automatic), libpython2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.8-6, automatic), libhogweed2:i386 (2.7.1-3, automatic), libpython-stdlib:i386 (2.7.8-1, automatic), samba:i386 (4.1.11+dfsg-1, automatic), libhdb9-heimdal:i386 (1.6~rc2+dfsg-8, automatic), python-samba:i386 (4.1.11+dfsg-1, automatic), libldb1:i386 (1.1.17-1, automatic), libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 (3.3.7-2, automatic), samba-dsdb-modules:i386 (4.1.11+dfsg-1, automatic), libdb5.3:i386 (5.3.28-6, automatic), winbind:i386 (4.1.11+dfsg-1, automatic), samba-libs:i386 (4.1.11+dfsg-1, automatic)
Upgrade: libtalloc2:i386 (2.0.7+git20120207-1, 2.1.1-2), libnih-dbus1:i386 (1.0.3-4ubuntu11, 1.0.3-4.3), smbclient:i386 (3.6.6-3ubuntu5, 4.1.11+dfsg-1), libc-dev-bin:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu20, 2.19-10), python2.7:i386 (2.7.3-5ubuntu4, 2.7.8-6), python-minimal:i386 (2.7.3-0ubuntu7, 2.7.8-1), libsmbclient:i386 (3.6.6-3ubuntu5, 4.1.11+dfsg-1), python2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.3-5ubuntu4, 2.7.8-6), libp11-kit0:i386 (0.13-1, 0.20.3-2), samba-common-bin:i386 (3.6.6-3ubuntu5, 4.1.11+dfsg-1), locales:i386 (2.13+git20120306-3, 2.19-10), python:i386 (2.7.3-0ubuntu7, 2.7.8-1), libp11-kit-dev:i386 (0.13-1, 0.20.3-2), libpython2.7:i386 (2.7.3-5ubuntu4, 2.7.8-6), libwbclient0:i386 (3.6.6-3ubuntu5, 4.1.11+dfsg-1), libc6-dev:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu20, 2.19-10), cifs-utils:i386 (5.5-1ubuntu1, 6.4-1), samba-common:i386 (3.6.6-3ubuntu5, 4.1.11+dfsg-1), libc6:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu20, 2.19-10), libnih1:i386 (1.0.3-4ubuntu11, 1.0.3-4.3)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2014-09-09  09:07:10
```

This is so incredibly weird - it seems that before running the command

```
apt-get install cifs-utils
```

I had all the correct versions of everything... yes old but functional...

I had `libc6:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu20)` and `libc6-dev:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu20)`

Then the installer upgraded to 2.19 and THEN complained that the version 2.19 is too high... And what is worse, it seems that my system is now broken and I will never be able to install anything ?

This is crazy because I had to put a lot of effort into installing specific development tools and sdks required...

I hope there is a way to **DOWNGRADE** libc6 ?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

Comment: @dan08 please see update, what happened when I tried

Comment: 12.10 is [EOL](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) and no longer supported. PLease use 12.04 or 14.04.

Comment: That is wonderful but I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the deb packages required and installed using --downgrade-force

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/libc6